# Sublime Text Regular Expression (Select line below a specific character)

Tags: notepad++, sublimetext3

I try to select specific lines because I'm a translator, here I tried this command: "`(>)(.*\n){2}(.*)`"
but I don't want the first line, only the one below the ">" character, (below the timer)

What I have tried:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Notepad++.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `>.+\R\K.+`
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find All</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
>.+     # > followed by 1 or more any character but newline
\R      # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
\K      # forget all we have seen until this position
.+      # 1  or more any character but newline
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly!
but at times I have two lines (I forgot to say sorry)

I tried: ">.+\R\R\K.+", but it didn't work, how to select two lines if there are any?

Screen: https://i.imgur.com/Vwwwhuv.png

Comment: @Tibo1211: Use: `>(?:.+\R){2}\K.+`

Comment: Perfect!!! This `>.+\R\K.+` and `>(?:.+\R){2}\K.+`
Is there a way to merge the two commands?
To do it at the same time?

Or a command that does both, thanks!

Comment: @Tibo1211: Use a single regex, a better one for select 1 or 2 lines after the time is: `>.+\R\K(?:.+\R?){1,2}`